# When calling Array.prototype.slice will the new array have the same prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this copy array routine:

```
const copyArray = (a: HasIndex) => {

  const ret = a.slice(0);

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(a)) {
    ret[k] = v;
  }

  return ret;

};
```

I assume that calling `Array.prototype.slice` will not copy over the prototype from the original?

So maybe I should do:

```
const copyArray = (a: HasIndex) => {

  const ret = a.slice(0);

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(a)) {
    ret[k] = v;
  }

  Object.setPrototypeOf(ret, Object.getPrototypeOf(a)); // here?

  return ret;

};
```

Comment: Is `a` definitely an array? `Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === Array.prototype`?

Comment: Yeah, assume `a` is an array, but it could have some modified prototype (unlikely but possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not necessary, `slice()` alone is sufficient, because it will call the constructor of the passed object. (If the object is an array, it'll call the `Array` constructor - otherwise, it'll call whatever constructor the object has.) See the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice):

> 12. Let A be ArraySpeciesCreate(O, count).
>
> (...assign to properties of A and return A)

where ArraySpeciesCreate [is](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate):

> a. Let C be Get(originalArray, "constructor").
>
> 9.Return Construct(C, «length»).

In other words - if you call `Array.prototype.slice` on an array-like object whose prototype extends from Array but isn't `Array.prototype`, the passed object's constructor will be called. There's no need to set the prototype manually:

```js
class ExtendedArray extends Array {
  customMethod() {
    console.log('custom method');
  }
}
const e = new ExtendedArray();
const sliced = e.slice();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(sliced) === ExtendedArray.prototype);
sliced.customMethod();
```